# Handle specific exception type in python

Tags: python, exception

I have some code that handles an exception, and I want to do something specific only if it's a specific exception, and only in debug mode. So for example:

```
try:
    stuff()
except Exception as e:
    if _debug and e is KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()
    logging.exception("Normal handling")
```

As such, I don't want to just add a:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

because I'm trying to keep the difference in this debug code minimal

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well, really, you probably should keep the handler for `KeyboardInterrupt` separated. Why would you only want to handle keyboard interrupts in debug mode, but swallow them otherwise?

That said, you can use `isinstance` to check the type of an object:

```
try:
    stuff()
except Exception as e:
    if _debug and isinstance(e, KeyboardInterrupt):
        sys.exit()
    logger.exception("Normal handling")
```

Comment: This is on an embedded system running without a shell. So we could only possibly get a keyboard interrupt in debug mode. So we just handle all exceptions.

Answer (score 21):

This is pretty much the way it's done.

```
try:
    stuff()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    if _debug:
        sys.exit()
    logging.exception("Normal handling")
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception("Normal handling")
```

There's minimal repetition.  Not zero, however, but minimal.

If the "normal handling" is more than one line of code, you can define a function to avoid repetition of the two lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Either use the standard method mentioned in the other answers, or if you really want to test within the except block then you can use [isinstance()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance).

```
try:
    stuff()
except Exception as e:
   if _debug and isinstance(e, KeyboardInterrupt):
        sys.exit()
    logging.exception("Normal handling")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should let KeyboardInterrupt bubble all the way up and trap it at the highest level.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()
    except:
        pass

def main():
    try:
        stuff()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception("Normal handling")
        if _debug:
            raise e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    stuff()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    if _debug:
        sys.exit()
    logging.exception("Normal handling")
except ValueError:
    if _debug:
        sys.exit()
    logging.exception("Value error Normal handling")
else:
    logging.info("One more message without exception")
```

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with

```
try:
    stuff()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    if _debug:
        logging.exception("Debug handling")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        logging.exception("Normal handling")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can name specific exceptions in Python:

```
try:
    stuff()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
except Exception:
    normal_handling()
```