# Python: do something for every Exception raised

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

Python's `try...except` construct allows one to catch more than one exception and do the same thing to each one (`except (Exception1, Exception2, ...):`), to do the same thing whether an Exception is raised or not (`finally:`) and to do something only if an exception is *not* raised (`else:`). Is there a way to handle each Exception separately, but then do the same thing (e.g. `sys.exit()`) if any of them occured? At the moment I am using this call separately for each `except`:

```
try:
    np.loadtxt(filename, ...)
except ValueError as e:
     # Handle the ValueError with a custom message here
     sys.exit(1)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
     # Handle missing file here
     sys.exit(1)
except SomeOtherErrorThatMightConceivablyBeRaised:
     # Handle it
     sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: wrap it in a function, and `return` within the `else` clause.  Put whatever handling you need after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can group exceptions in parenthesis as such:

```
try:
    np.loadtxt(filename, ...)
except (ValueError, 
        FileNotFoundError, 
        SomeOtherErrorThatMightConceivablyBeRaised) as e:
    # Handle the ValueError with a custom message here
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: The problem is that I'd like to do something different with each Exception _before_ `sys.exit(1)`.

Comment: You can group multiple exceptions in parenthesis, as Skylor suggested, and use an if statement to determine the exception type in 'catch' block. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329453/handle-specific-exception-type-in-python